# Rhino Security and POCO class

Tags: nhibernate, rhino-security

it seems if I want to use Rhino Security on an entity , that entity need to have a SecurityKey field of Guid type. I saw an example where the constructor of the entity's class has a statement that assign the SecurityKey

```
public class Document
{
  public Document() { SecurityKey = Guid.NewGuid(); } 
  public virtual int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual string Name { get; set;}
  public virtual Guid SecurityKey { get; set;}
}
public class DocumentInformationExtractor : IEntityInformationExtractor
{ .... }
```

The constructor assgined a new Guid SecurityKey everytimes.  I don't understand why this works. Should it not assgined a new Guid only for new entity that has not been persisted ?

Answer (score 1):

That's right. You have to do that otherwise the `Guid` saved would be `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`, but you need a proper, non-empty guid.
This field will be used when you call:

```
permissionsBuilderService
    .Allow("/Document/Edit")
    .For(user1)
    .On(MyDocument)
    .Level(20)
    .Save();
```

This is just used so you do not save an empty `SecurityKey` Guid, cause you might use in the future (you do not need to assign permissions if you don't need them). Rhino-Security will look after the load of the graph and populate `SecurityKey` with the one saved.